# Automorphism groups of vertex transitive graphs

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, algebraic-graph-theory

Does there exist a finite nonoriented graph whose automorphism group is transitive but not [generously transitive](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Generously_transitive_group_action) (that is, it is not true that each pair $(x,y)$ of vertices can be interchanged by some automorphism)?

I know, for example, that Cayley graphs are always generously vertex-transitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cayley graphs for abelian groups have generously transitive automorphism groups. In general a Cayley graph for a non-abelian group will not be generously transitive.

In particular if $G$ is not abelian and $X$ is a so-called graphical regular representation (abbreviated GRR) for $G$, then its automorphism group is not generously transitive. The key property of a GRR is that the stabilizer of a vertex is trivial.

Constructing GRRs is not trivial, but it is expected that most Cayley graphs for groups that are not abelian or generalized dicylic will be GRRs - so choosing a connection set at random usually works.

Comment: So this answer has some connection to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328730/uniformity-in-colorings-of-a-graph/330239?noredirect=1#comment824772_330239) question, I think?

Answer (score 2):

To provide a more explicit example: Take two vertices of distance 2 on the [truncated tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_tetrahedron). Observe that there is a unique path between these vertices, and that the edges in this path are distinct (only one of them is part of a triangle, for instance). So we can define a direction on this path, and thus can't hope to flip it in an automorphism.

Answer (score 0):

This one, unless I'm mistaken...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecahedron